# How to conditionally trigger htmx post behavior based on JavaScript function's return value

Tags: javascript, htmx

```
<script defer>
  function validateForm() {
      textInputs = document.getElementsByName("text");
      
      const errorMessageDiv = document.getElementById("error_message_text");
      for (input of textInputs) {          
          if (input.value === "") {              
              errorMessageDiv.textContent = "Erro! Pelo menos uma alternativa está em branco"
              return false; 
          }
      }
      errorMessageDiv.textContent = "";
      return true; 
  }
  
</script>
<form class="form" 
name="form_questao" 
id="form_question"
onsubmit="return validateForm()"
hx-post = {{request.path}}
>
```

I want to halt the htmx post request if the validateForm() function returns false. Despite being a simple matter, I couldn't find a satisfactory solution to this problem. Since there are other htmx codes in this HTML file, using htmx:beforerequest could lead to conflicts and unexpected behaviors. Thanks!!!
In the documentation, I found the 'Standard Event Filters.' In my case, I could use hx-trigger='submit[validateForm()]'. However, another issue arises because i can't resend another submission; I need to reload the page to unblock the hx-trigger.

Comment: What conflicts and unexpected behaviours are you worried about with `beforeRequest`? It is an approach that works well.

Comment: Hi McPherson, thank you for the response. I think that since there are multiple htmx requests in the HTML, the beforeRequest will be triggered by any one of them, causing the function to trigger when it shouldn't.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you listen to the event on the form, it will just listen to events sent by the form (or its children). If there are htmx events being sent by the children, you can simply check if the event was sent by the form or from its children.

Comment: Hi McPherson, thank you for the response. After many hours, I realized the problem lies with the Summernote text editor I'm using in the 'text' element. As I'm using htmx with the 'beforeend' attribute to dynamically obtain forms, Summernote only sends the data of the first element, leaving the rest empty (""), which led to my misunderstanding of the problem.